# Dyn sql convert failed

Tags: sql, sql-server

Всем привет, помогите пофиксить ошибку, что-то не могу сам догадаться.

```
declare @FILENAME varchar(512) = 'filename', @SQL nvarchar(4000), @DT varchar(max)

set @DT='Data Source=\\domain.local\folder\' + @FILENAME +'.xlsx'+ ';Extended Properties=EXCEL 12.0'

set @SQL = 'insert into #t (f1, f2, f3)
SELECT convert(varchar, [comment]), fieldOne, fieldTwo
FROM OPENDATASOURCE(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''' + @DT + ''')...[Sheet$];'

exec sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Выходит ошибка:
**Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2019-08-23 17:42:58, 151 сек' to data type int.**

Comment: для начала уберите insert into ... convert(varchar, [comment]), чтоб исключить проблему в этом месте

Comment: и покажите временную таблицу #t